# Access Key from Values and Value from Key

Tags: c++, boost, stl

My project needs both accessors.

- Access Value using Key (Simple)
- Access Key using Value (Bit tricky)

Value too will be unique in my project

---

Please suggest the better container to use and how ?

I would like to use either the STL or BOOST.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called a [bidirectional map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map).

There isn't one in the STL, but you can take a look at [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/) for another implementation.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can simply use two regular one-way maps. If you use pointers, there should be little memory overhead and decent performance.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I used in my project two days ago.

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
class ClientManager
{
    typedef boost::bimap<
        boost::bimaps::set_of<int>,
        boost::bimaps::set_of<int>
    > ConnectedUsers; // User Id, Instance Id
    ConnectedUsers m_connectedUsers;
public:
    int getUserId(int instanceId);
    int getInstanceId(int userId);
};

int ClientManager::getInstanceId(int userId)
{
    auto it = m_connectedUsers.left.find(userId);
    return it->second;
}

int ClientManager::getUserId(int instanceId)
{
    auto it = m_connectedUsers.right.find(instanceId);
    return it->second;
}

...

// Insert
m_connectedUsers.insert(ConnectedUsers::value_type(id, instanceId));

// Erase
m_connectedUsers.left.erase(userId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and simple example. That was very east to understand

Comment: Which makes us not west much time.

Comment: @kaps If this solution fully answers your question you can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the either way access, ie *key->value and value->key*, chances are that your design doesn't need an associative container like a `map`

Try a `vector` of [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

On a side note, if you need to store more than two values, you can use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

HTH!!

Comment: Can you clarify why you think that a design calling for "efficient access both ways" is unlikely?